# Terraform vsphere_resource_pool on connected standalone ESXi host - error fetching resource pool

Tags: terraform, devops, vsphere

I'm pretty much a noob with terraform and the vsphere provider, and I'm bumping up into all the noob problems.

We're hoping to land a VM on a managed standalone (not clustered) ESXi 65 host connected to vsphere, but I can't get the resource_pool resource statement correct and, as shown, I got a little desperate and tried all permutations I could think of:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  vsphere_server = "vcs1.fq.dn"
  alias = "prod"
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "prod" {
  provider = vsphere.prod
  name = "PROD Datacenter"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "vmhost23" {
  provider = vsphere.prod
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.prod.id

#  name          = "vmhost23/Resources"
#  name          = "vmhost23/resources"
#  name          = "vmhost23/"
#  name          = "/"
  name          = "/Resources"
#  name          = "/resources"

#  name          = "vmhost23/Resources/"
#  name          = "vmhost23/resources/"
#  name          = "vmhost23/"
#  name          = "/"
#  name          = "/Resources/"
#  name          = "/resources/"

#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn"
#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn/"
#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn/Resources/"
#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn/Resources"
#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn/resources/"
#  name          = "vmhost23.fq.dn/resources"

}
```

unfortunately, there's just no joy:

```
data.vsphere_datacenter.prod: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_datastore.vmhost23: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_resource_pool.vmhost23: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_network.DMZ-prod: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_datacenter.dc: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_datastore.datastore: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_datastore_cluster.datastore_cluster: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_network.TEST-APP: Refreshing state...
data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template: Refreshing state...
:
vsphere_virtual_machine.prdsat: Refreshing state... [id=42190b77-a6a7-8693-e05f-c11528d1afa4]

Error: error fetching resource pool: resource pool '/Resources' not found

  on vm-prdsplidx01x.tf line 4, in data "vsphere_resource_pool" "vmhost23":
   4: data "vsphere_resource_pool" "vmhost23" {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In my case, the fact that the host is in a folder - yeah, really - makes all the difference.  It was such an insignificant data point that I ignored it.

So, in my case, what worked was

```
data "vsphere_resource_pool" "vmhost23" {
  provider = vsphere.prod
  name          = "FolderName/vmhost23.fq.dn"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.prod.id
}
```

Capitalization is important, and it seems to need the FQDN on the ESXi hostname; but definitely correct me if you found a way to make it work with short-hostnames or lower-case folder names.

So, another hurdle down and only 31 to go!  Thanks for playing Duck for me.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled DRS/HA on my vCenter7 which helped getting resource_pool. Also using govc will get the path to resource pool ID.

govc about
govc find / -type p

terraform import vsphere_resource_pool.resource_pool /dc1/host/compute-cluster1/Resources/
The above gets you the tfstate.